# How to let users enter text into <li> without using input fields?

Tags: jquery

The text placeholders are a list of list items.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: At the *very least* you should clarify your intent (what're you doing with the changed list-item's text?), and, if possible, show what you've already tried (it's not always necessary to have tried something, but it gives us a starting point to work from if you have).

Comment: Isn't the title the question?

Comment: I don't understand these forums of closed questions. The question was pretty obvious and clear. Maybe it was outside the domain of expertise so in their confusion they simply closed the question. That actually makes more sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

place an attribute of contenteditable="true" like so:

```
<li contenteditable="true">text to edit</li>
```

i built kitgui.com from scratch and it uses this technique. i would look at the techniques in UI there so you can get an idea of a good INLINE approach

you need to also have a way for people to save things which is a whole other answer

Comment: this is the answer, why the downvote? Someone is very ignorant here.

Comment: Indeed. The normal way is to use input fields to enter text and I am looking for a different approach to look into for a cleaner code. I am not looking for a full implementation as yet. Contenteditable will be a good start. Thanks to those that have suggested it.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add the `contentEditable` attribute to the relevant `li` elements:

```
<li contentEditable>placeholder text</li>
```

This isn't necessarily a wonderful solution, however, due to the cross-browser support for `contentEditable` and because you've not specified what your intent is (should they just be editable for the user's entertainment, or are you submitting the changed text to a database or using the values client-side in a script of some kind?).

Comment: It will be validated and saved in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can attach the .keypress() event to your LI items and switch based on the key?

**EDIT:**
Well if anyone is interested, it seems the funky keypress() method works if we attach it to the body of the page. See the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/36RX3/9/